# jquery title attribute text pop-up hide

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm currently using the title attribute of my 'a' tag to show and hide images that correspond with this tag.

However, when you hover on the 'a' there is the annoying title text that pops up.

Can I disable this pop-up text with out completely disabling the title attribute? ANy help is great!

Cheers,

DanC

-----edit------

here is the working code which passes as xhtml strict!!!!

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(\"ul.projects li a\").hover(
    function(){

    var largeAlt = $(this).attr(\"class\");

    $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").attr({ src: largeAlt }); 
    $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").fadeIn();

},
    function(){

    $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").attr({ src: \"\" }); 
    $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").fadeIn();

});
```

});

Comment: please post some code of what you are trying to do. Show us the html and the jquery-code you wrote.

Comment: its all good, have just realised you can use any attribute when swapping image paths so I have transferred the directory path the the 'a' id rather than the title, getting rid of the pop-ups!

$(\"ul.projects li a\").hover(
  function(){
           
        var largeAlt = $(this).attr(\"id\");
      
     $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").attr({ src: largeAlt }); 
     $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").fadeIn();

 },
  function(){
  
  $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").attr({ src: \"\" }); 
     $(\"ul.image_display li#image_hover img\").fadeIn();

 });

Comment: Edit the post to paste the code there. Cause it's all cranked up if you post it as a comment :-)

Comment: You can check our my answer for another method which you can implement.

Comment: i have edited the question to show the answer that has been developed! cheers for the help people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using your own custom attributes instead of using the "title" attribute.

```
<a customtagattribute="some value" id="link1" href="#">Linkety!</a>
```

EDIT: [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) key value pairs can also be used like this -

```
var links = { "link1": "attribute value 1", "link2": "attribute value 2", ... };
```

Comment: yeah, have just done something similar, cheers for the answer though!

Comment: only problem is that you won't have valid xhtml. If you consider that as a problem that is.

Comment: yeah have just noticed the lack of validation, must be a work around for this........

Comment: You can use a JSON key value pair instead of attributes if you want valid XHTML. Check the answer for more details.

Comment: All good again!! If you put the directory as 'class' it passes, even as xhtml strict

Answer (score 1):

Not really, it's the way the browsers are supposed to behave. If you want to map this data, you might want to establish a Javascript data structure that defines the mappings separately. I'm not sure if there is a good semantic way to establish the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the anchor's id property? If the path to the image is included (i.e. characters not allowed in IDs), you could use an AJAX request with the ID to get the actual URL (or the actual image).